# When does recurly sends notification emails to users?

Tags: recurly

I am using Recurly to manage subscription on my web app. During a billing cycle I may call 
*subscription.update_attributes(:plan_code => 'xxx', :timeframe => 'renewal')* 
multiple times but I don't want users to get notified again and again. Can I configure Recurly so it does not do so? I would like to notify users only 3 days before current billing cycle ends

Comment: I just tried again and it seems recurly won't send notification email if timeframe is set to 'renewal'. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable your **Subscription Change** email from being sent to users. This way they'll only be notified when their subscription actually renews and they're sent the **Payment Receipt** email.

Recurly also does have a **Renewal Reminder** email which is sent 7 days (configurable today) before current bill cycle ends.

Take a look at your email settings page (app.recurly.com/go/emails) to enable, disable, or edit any of these emails.